# Oracle query - Displaying data grouped yearly

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I am trying to display data grouped by 12 months period based on the min start date.  If FTE was changed during the 12 month period, it will be listed with corresponding start and end date. Test data is provided as part of [[Data grouped by date in oracle sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42307617/data-grouped-by-date-in-oracle-sql][1])

For example start date is 19/05/2008. So year start is 19/05/2008 and Year end is 18/05/2009. If the FTE was changed between 19/05/2009 and 18/05/2010, then the result set will have 2 lines during the 2nd anniversary period.

```
YearEmployeeJob Start date  end date    FTE Year_start  Year_end
1   1111    1   19/05/2008  18/05/2009  100 19/05/2008  18/05/2009
2   1111    1   19/05/2009  18/05/2010  100 19/05/2009  18/05/2010
3   1111    1   19/05/2010  18/05/2011  100 19/05/2010  18/05/2011
4   1111    1   19/05/2011  17/05/2012  100 19/05/2011  17/05/2012
5   1111    1   19/05/2012  18/05/2013  100 19/05/2012  18/05/2013
6   1111    1   19/05/2013  27/11/2013  100 19/05/2013  18/05/2014
6   1111    1   28/11/2013  18/05/2014  60  19/05/2013  18/05/2014
7   1111    1   19/05/2014  18/05/2015  60  19/05/2014  18/05/2015
8   1111    1   19/05/2015  24/08/2015  60  19/05/2015  17/05/2016
8   1111    1   25/08/2015  18/05/2016  68.571  19/05/2015  17/05/2016
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer back to the solution provided in your original thread [Data grouped by date in oracle sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42307617/data-grouped-by-date-in-oracle-sql/42308061#42308061)

In the solution below, I add one more bit of information to that query, in a column labeled `y` - to show the number of years (rounded UP to the nearest integer) for each interval created there. I use this bit in the additional, enveloping (outer) query to generate "annual" intervals as in your new requirement. The standard way to do that is with a traditional hierarchical query, as demonstrated below.

```
select   level as yr, employee, job,
         add_months(start_date, 12 * (level - 1)) as start_date,
         case when level < y then add_months(start_date, 12 * level) - 1
              else end_date end    as end_date,
         FTE
from (
  select   employee, job, min(start_date) as start_date, max(end_date) as end_date, FTE,
           ceil(months_between(max(end_date), min(start_date))/12) as y
  from     ( select employee, job, start_date, end_date, FTE,
                 row_number() over (partition by employee, job      order by start_date) -
                 row_number() over (partition by employee, job, FTE order by start_date) 
                                                                                 as grp
             from t
           )
  group by employee, job, FTE, grp
     )
connect by level <= y
    and prior employee   = employee
    and prior start_date = start_date
    and prior sys_guid() is not null
order by employee, start_date       -- if needed
;
```

**Output**:

```
 YR EMPLOYEE   JOB   START_DATE  END_DATE           FTE
--- ---------- ----- ----------- ----------- ----------
  1 1111       1     19-May-2008 18-May-2009        100
  2 1111       1     19-May-2009 18-May-2010        100
  3 1111       1     19-May-2010 18-May-2011        100
  4 1111       1     19-May-2011 18-May-2012        100
  5 1111       1     19-May-2012 18-May-2013        100
  6 1111       1     19-May-2013 27-Nov-2013        100
  1 1111       1     28-Nov-2013 27-Nov-2014         60
  2 1111       1     28-Nov-2014 24-Aug-2015         60
  1 1111       1     25-Aug-2015 24-Aug-2016     68.571
  2 1111       1     25-Aug-2016 11-Sep-2016     68.571
  1 1111       1     12-Sep-2016 29-Sep-2016     72.857
  1 1111       1     30-Sep-2016 10-Nov-2016     91.429
  1 1111       1     11-Nov-2016 23-Apr-2017        100
  1 1111       1     24-Apr-2017 14-Jan-2018         60
  1 1111       1     15-Jan-2018 14-Jan-2019     71.429
  2 1111       1     15-Jan-2019 31-May-2019     71.429
  1 1111       1     01-Jun-2019 31-May-2020        100
  2 1111       1     01-Jun-2020 31-May-2021        100
  3 1111       1     01-Jun-2021 31-May-2022        100
  4 1111       1     01-Jun-2022 31-May-2023        100
  5 1111       1     01-Jun-2023 31-May-2024        100
        .............................
 29 1111       1     01-Jun-2047 31-May-2048        100
 30 1111       1     01-Jun-2048 31-May-2049        100
 31 1111       1     01-Jun-2049 31-Dec-2049        100

47 rows selected.
```